# Intermediate Value Theorem converse confusion

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Determine if $f(x)=20\sin(x+3)(\cos\frac{x^2}{2})=-10$ in the interval $[0,5]$.

Why can't we say using Intermediate Value theorem that $f(x)\neq-10$ in the provided interval? The explanation states that The Intermediate Value Theorem will only tell us that -10 will exist. The theorem will NOT tell us that -10 don’t exist.

Comment: The intermediate value theorem is an if-then type result, not an if and only if type result.

Comment: For example, let $f(x) = x^2$ on the interval $[-2,3]$. Note that $f(-2) = 4$ and $f(3) = 9$.By your proposed reasoning, the Intermediate Value Theorem would say $f(x) = 0$ is not possible on the interval $[-2,3]$, but of course, that's simply false..

Comment: Ohh got it thanks

Comment: $f(0)\approx 2.82;\;f(1)\approx -13.3$ so there is at least one value of $x\in (0,1)$ where $f(x)=-10$